# SSL Certificates in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, certificate-authority, certificate-store

I have created my own CA and signed a certificate for use on an internal HTTPS website. I have imported the CA Certificate into both the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and the Intermediate Certificate Authorities on the IIS machine and the site certificate is bound to the site on port 4433.

This works fine on IE9 and Firefox (i.e. the site is trusted) but I still get an HTTPS with a red score through it in Chrome (version 23.0.1271.91) saying that the site is not trusted.

Everything I have come across thus far says add the CA to Trusted.... But this seems to be of no avail in Chrome.

Any Ideas?

Comment: As I wrote this I thought the port may be an issue, so I swapped it to 443 [after stopping Skype] but the https error remains!

Comment: Are you sure you imported your CA certificate? `chrome://chrome/settings/certificates` 'Authorities' section.

Comment: From the three bar icon at the top right corner of screen, I selected: Settings\Show Advanced Settings\Manage Certificates - which takes me to the Windows Certificate Page. A lot of articles mention selecting "under the hood" but I do not have [cannot find]  this menu in Chrome (ver 23.0.1271.91).

Comment: I Just tried to address chrome://chrome/settings/certificates directly - it takes you to the same place as the menu driven navigation that I was using.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a server/IIS issue.
Try to restart the server and check your SSL expiration date....
Check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231738/cookie-only-sets-in-ie-and-not-firefox-chrome)  it might help you